# C# / Nodejs compatible encryption/decryption

Tags: c#, javascript, node.js, openssl

What's the equivalent C# encryption routine for the following nodejs code:

```
var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes256', 'myPassword');
encrypted = cipher.update(sha256, 'utf8', 'base64') + cipher.final('base64');
```

I want to encrypt on C# and be able to decrypt it in a Node.js app.

Comment: Have you looked into http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms834104.aspx also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndael%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, but the C# implementation (MSDN) requires a key and iv explicitly set, whereas the nodejs / openssl implementation is just using a password - probably generating the key/iv internally.

Comment: From the node.js documentation: http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipheriv_algorithm_key_iv you can specify the key and IV